# Migration of Spring 3 / Mule 3 Embedded Web Application To Spring Boot / Spring 5 / Mule 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mule, mule-esb

We have an existing Mule 3.x / Spring 3.x web application where mule runs embedded. We have flows for CXF web services.

We are now moving to Spring 5.x / Spring Boot. I believe that means we must move to mule 4.x.

- can someone help me understand the steps needed?
- can we even run Mule 4 embedded in our Spring war application? (mule context listener)
- it appears that the mule 3 CXF web services approach has been repalced by APIKit?

Based on the Mule 4.x documentation, it appears that they are not focused on this packaging option. Instead they can embed a mule application in tomcat.

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 0):

A migration guide can be found here:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-module-spring

> The Spring module doesn’t ship with any particular Spring dependency.
>   You can provide whatever ones you need by adding the following to your
>   application’s pom.xml. To use the Spring module, simply add it to your
>   application using the Studio palette or add the following dependency
>   in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-spring-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version> <!-- or newer -->
  <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: following line ??

Comment: What is the convention being used for mule maven repositories mule 3 vs mule 4)?  

I see:
 org.mule.modules
 org.mule.runtime
 
I am trying to find the builders so i can include MuleXmlBuilderContextServlet